# Apache Pig: Process Long Space

Tags: apache-pig

I am learning Apache Pig and I am trying to process the Dataset like below. It has the list of Movie names and its genre. Both Seperated as long Space or Multiple tabs.

**Dataset sample**

```
"!Next?" (1994)                     Documentary
"#1 Single" (2006)                  Reality-TV
"#1MinuteNightmare" (2014)              Horror
"#30Nods" (2014)                    Drama
"#7DaysLater" (2013)                    Comedy
"#ATown" (2014)                     Comedy
"#Actress" (2015)                   Comedy
"#Adulthood" (????)                 Comedy
"#Adulting" (2015)                  Comedy
"#AwkwardMornings" (2014)               Comedy
"#Bandcamp" (2014)                  Musical
"#Besties" (2014)                   Comedy
```

When I tried to Load the Dataset, its loading only the Movie name part like below

**LOAD command**

```
grunt> X = LOAD '/home/padhu/Downloads/smallgenre.txt' AS (line:chararray);
```

**Output:**

```
("!Next?" (1994))
("#1 Single" (2006))
("#1MinuteNightmare" (2014))
("#30Nods" (2014))
("#7DaysLater" (2013))
```

I also tried like below but getting the same output as above

```
X = LOAD '/home/padhu/Downloads/smallgenre.txt' AS (line:chararray,line2:Chararray);
```

And I tried like this and getting the output partially, I am getting only movie names if the movie name itself contains spaces.

```
X = LOAD '/home/padhu/Downloads/smallgenre.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (line:chararray,line2:Chararray);
```

I am expecting the output to be like below

```
(MovieName,genre)
```

Is there anyway to Write a PIG statement to ignore the spaces in Movie names and consider the space between Movie name and Space as delemeter ?

I did search in google and SO before posting this, but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script is not elegant but works for me :

```
 A = LOAD '/home/padhu/Downloads/smallgenre.txt' USING TextLoader() as (line:chararray);
 B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line, '      ',2)) AS (MovieName:CHARARRAY, Type:CHARARRAY);
 C = FOREACH B GENERATE MovieName, LTRIM(Type) AS Genre;
 DUMP C;
```